# SwiftUI sheet modal background not working with edgesIgnoreSafeArea(.all) - WHY?

Tags: background, swiftui

I'm running iOS 13 simulator with a SwiftUI sheet modal - trying to paint the sheet background and ignore safe areas - but there's still white sheet showing.  Any ideas on how to do this properly?

```
    var body: some View {
        VStack(alignment: .center, spacing: 0) {

... redacted ...

 }   // VStack
            .background(Color.gray.edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all))
```

[iPhone Simulator with sheet modal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hI39k.png)

See the image (attached)

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Expand top container (`VStack` in your case) to full sheet area, like

```
VStack {
    // ... your content
}
.frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: .infinity)      // << here !!
.background(Color.gray.edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all))
```

Comment: OK will thy that.  What side effects will that have?

Comment: No-one, it is valid feature.

Comment: Thank you - just tried it and it works like a charm!

Comment: For me, I didn't need the `.frame` modifier. I only needed the `.edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)` on my background color.

Answer (score 0):

Best way to paint the background is using a ZStack:

```
    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            // replace with the color you want
            Color.green
                .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)
            

            VStack {
                // put view's Content here
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: yes, that's one way - there's others... so the "best" is subjective... adding a ZStack just for a sheet background seems like a poor choice to me.... when there is a .background() method.

Comment: using asperi's method, both your painted background and your vstack's content will ignore the safe area (and probably even extend more), which is not a good thing, unless you know what you're doing (there is a reason its called `safeArea`). also talking with my experience, its not good to let swiftui decide the frame's width and height in these situations (like asperi's answer). swiftui currently has many sizing problems, and i have experienced situations that those sizing problems made the app crash due to high cpu usage (basically app would call UIKit's sizeToFit method far too many times)

Comment: i'd even recommend adding a `.frame(width: UIScreen.main.bounds.width)` to the end of the VStack of my own answer. again, i've experienced bad confusing swiftui problems with sizings, and there is a good chance they might occur to you too.